# how to extract data from special formated string

Tags: java

I have string in this format

```
< value1 >,< value2 >, <1,2,3,4,5>,< some value >
```

the output must be an array of Strings:

```
array[0] = "value1";
array[1] = "value2";
array[2] = "1,2,3,4,5";
array[3] = "some value";
```

Any suggestion what is the best way to do that?

Comment: We need some more rigorous definition of the format. Is the array in the middle always 5 elements? If not, how do you know how long it is? Can the values contain commas too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a little bit of regex magic?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String myString = "< value1 >,< value2 >, <1,2,3,4,5>,< some value >";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)[^>]++(?=>)");
    final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(myString);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group().trim());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
1,2,3,4,5
some value
```

Comment: @Djon I already tested it, didn't work. Next time **test your answer** before even dare to post it.

Comment: No, `.*` would grab the `>` at the end. You have to use `[^>]++`. You could use `<([^>]++)>` and then use `m.group(1)` to grab the bit in the middle.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I assumed it would do the look ahead and find the `>` on its own, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        String input = "< value1 >,< value2 >, <1,2,3,4,5>,< some value >";
        String [] output = splitter(input);
        assertEquals("value1", output[0]);
        assertEquals("value2", output[1]);
        assertEquals("1,2,3,4,5", output[2]);
        assertEquals("some value", output[3]);
    }

    private String[] splitter(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(">\\s*,\\s*<");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            String s = split[i];
            s = s.replaceAll("<", "");
            s = s.replaceAll(">", "");
            s = s.trim();
            split[i] = s;
        }
        return split;
    }


}
```

Comment: Note that you changed your input in the middle of me writing this, so it's no longer correct.

Comment: I assumed that the `<` and `>` where there for illustrative purposes. Otherwise this would certainly work.

Comment: this is not a valid solution, notice there might be spaces >, <

Comment: @kdureidy there wasn't when you first wrote your question.  I'll have to change this answer.  Give me a few

Comment: this is a valid solution, thank you for your effort, but the regex solution is more generic

Comment: @kdureidy fair enough :)  This is a little messy.  If this were in my app I'd make the code more readable anyway.

Comment: @TieTYT This is not my code at all, I just have to deal with it :)

Comment: I could do similar code, I just wanted something more generic, since i am weak in REGEX, i decided to ask how to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it in one line:

```
String[] array = input.replaceAll("(^< *)|( *>$)", "").split(" *>, *< *");
```